Dymos: Restoration failure when splitting up ODE into two components
I have been building an optimal control simulation similar to the racecar example from the documentation (https://openmdao.org/dymos/docs/latest/examples/racecar/racecar.html). In my model there is a vehicle dynamics model that calculates the accelerations in the vehicle reference frame, based on the forces produced by the tires and the current velocities of the vehicle.
The tire forces are calculated by a second component that takes the vehicle velocities (states) and applied torques (controls) using simple linear relations (longitudinal force scales linearly with torque, lateral force scales with slip angle). Finally there is a third component that calculates the grip limits of the tire based on a friction circle. See the XDSM below:
XDSM
When I try to run this I get a restoration failure from IPOPT. Checking the total derivatives against complex step gives me this output:
 'traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:r'    | 'traj.phase0.states:n'  |  9.8677e-02 |  9.8723e-02 |  3.0820e-03 |  3.1218e-02 |  >ABS_TOL >REL_TOL |
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 'traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:r'    | 'traj.phase0.states:r'  |  1.0607e+01 |  1.0607e+01 |  2.3431e-03 |  2.2091e-04 |  >ABS_TOL >REL_TOL |
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 'traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:r'    | 'traj.phase0.states:u'  |  7.0988e-02 |  7.1729e-02 |  4.4107e-03 |  6.1491e-02 |  >ABS_TOL >REL_TOL |
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 'traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:r'    | 'traj.phase0.states:v'  |  2.7646e-02 |  2.9618e-02 |  3.5225e-03 |  1.1893e-01 |  >ABS_TOL >REL_TOL |
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 'traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:r'    | 'traj.phase0.states:xi' |  1.6765e+00 |  1.6593e+00 |  5.8082e-02 |  3.5004e-02 |  >ABS_TOL >REL_TOL |
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 'traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:v'    | 'traj.phase0.states:n'  |  1.3974e+00 |  1.3982e+00 |  7.9276e-03 |  5.6700e-03 |  >ABS_TOL >REL_TOL |
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 'traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:v'    | 'traj.phase0.states:r'  |  4.4467e+01 |  4.4466e+01 |  6.6054e-03 |  1.4855e-04 |  >ABS_TOL >REL_TOL |
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 'traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:v'    | 'traj.phase0.states:u'  |  7.9225e-01 |  7.9746e-01 |  1.1748e-02 |  1.4732e-02 |  >ABS_TOL >REL_TOL |
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 'traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:v'    | 'traj.phase0.states:v'  |  1.0619e+01 |  1.0620e+01 |  9.0666e-03 |  8.5377e-04 |  >ABS_TOL >REL_TOL |
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 'traj.phase0.collocation_constraint.defects:v'    | 'traj.phase0.states:xi' |  1.2890e+01 |  1.2893e+01 |  1.3847e-01 |  1.0740e-02 |  >ABS_TOL >REL_TOL |
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+

I have checked all the partials using the complex step method as was done in the baristochrome example and they should all be correct.
When I merge the vehicle dynamics and tire force calculation blocks into one block the optimisation runs great and there are no problems whatsoever. This led me to think that there might have been missing information about the partial derivatives of the slip angles that are used to caclulate the tire force, thus I tried moving the slip angle calculation to the TireForce component. This did not solve the issue however so there might be something else going wrong here.

When the partials are correct but the totals are wrong, this strongly suggests that there is feedback in your model but not an appropriate nonlinear solver to converge the nonlinear system, AND not an appropriate linear solver to solve the total derivatives.
I would recommend adding a DirectSolver to the smallest group possible which contains the feedback loop, as well as a NewtonSolver
or NonlinearBlockGS solver. In your case that would be a group that contains only Vehicle dynamics and Tire. If this is one large group then you can add the solvers to it and it will work, but it will evaluate the other components not involved in the feedback more than necessary.
Recall that the theory OpenMDAO uses to solve derivatives means solving a system of linear equations once any residuals have been driven reasonably close to zero.  The default solvers are performant for the common case when no feedback is involved, but other solvers are needed when feedback is present.
